# JavaFX Concurrency : Update multiple messages from Service

Tags: java, javafx

How can we update multiple controls from a single Service. Right now there is only one single `updateMessage()` in Service, whose value can be bound to just one control and hence update just that. How can we update values for multiple controls ?

My instance of Service Class:

```
//run a background thread
threadTimeChecker = new Service<Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Task<Void> createTask() {
           return new Task<Void>() {
               @Override
               protected Void call() throws Exception {
                   while (!isDone) {
                       DataHelper.setCurrentDate(LocalDate.now());
                       if(!DataHelper.getOldDate().equals(DataHelper.getCurrentDate())) {
                          DataHelper.setIntIndex(DataHelper.getIntIndex()+1);
                          DataHelper.setOldDate(DataHelper.getCurrentDate());
                          DataHelper.saveData();
                          System.out.println("Saved!");
                       }
                       //Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                       updateMessage(wordString.getValue());
                   }
                   return null;
               }
           };
      }
};
threadTimeChecker.restart();

//bind string properties to labels
word.textProperty().bind(threadTimeChecker.messageProperty());
```

This only updates one message i.e. I can only bind one label. Is there any way I can update multiple messages from the same thread so I can bind multiple labels in my UI?

**EDITED** - More Information according to comments

My runnable is:

```
@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            //loop run until the program is closed
            while (!isDone) {
                DataHelper.setCurrentDate(LocalDate.now());
                if (!DataHelper.getOldDate().equals(DataHelper.getCurrentDate())) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DataHelper.setIntIndex(DataHelper.getIntIndex()+1);
                        }
                    });
                    DataHelper.setOldDate(DataHelper.getCurrentDate());
                    DataHelper.saveData();
                }
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

I run a thread to change `DataHelper.IntIndex` which invokes a listener that changes the 'String Property' as per the index like:

```
//listener to detect change in index and assign strings of word,meaning, and sentence, accordingly
DataHelper.intIndexProperty().addListener(
        (v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            wordString.setValue(DataHelper.getListOfWords().get((int) newValue).get("word"));
            meaningString.setValue(DataHelper.getListOfWords().get((int) newValue).get("meaning"));
            sentenceString.setValue(DataHelper.getListOfWords().get((int) newValue).get("sentence"));
            System.out.print("kjbmmj");
        }
);
```

And I have used these 'String Properties' to bind to three different labels correspondingly like:

```
//bind string properties to labels
word.textProperty().bind(wordString);
meaning.textProperty().bind(meaningString);
sentence.textProperty().bind(sentenceString);
```

Now what I want to do is to use more **JavaFX** ***inclined*** `updateMessage` to achieve the same.

Comment: Do you want to bind the same message to multiple labels?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Nope. I want a thread to give multiple messages to multiple labels.

Comment: You can't do that using `updateMessage()`. You can however use `Platform.runLater()` and update the respective labels in it.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha That's what I did at first in runnable thread first. But I wanted to do something better alternative to it for JavaFX. Now, I am going back again.

Comment: I am not sure how have you implemented the runnable but as far as I can see there is no need for multiple labels update. If you can edit your question and add more details on what you are trying to achieve, it can be helpful.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I have added details. Can you have a look at it once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of updating multiple messages, we just need to update a single instance of `DataHelper`. DataHelper has contents which will update multiple labels. For instance, let us consider we have the following labels which we want to update after each call of service :

- wordLabel
- meaningLabel
- sentenceLabel

To keep things simple, let us consider that you've a class `DataHelper` which has three properties word, meaning and sentence.

```
private class DataHelper {

   public DataHelper(String word, String meaning, String sentence) {
        this.word.setValue(word);
        this.meaning.setValue(meaning);
        this.sentence.setValue(sentence);
    }

   StringProperty word = new SimpleStringProperty();
   StringProperty meaning = new SimpleStringProperty();
   StringProperty sentence = new SimpleStringProperty();
   // setters and getters
}
```

We call the service for some background task and whenever the service is done with the background task it can return us the updated DataHelper.

```
Service<DataHelper> service = new Service<DataHelper>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<DataHelper> createTask() {
        return new Task<DataHelper>() {
            @Override
            protected DataHelper call() throws Exception {
                i.incrementAndGet(); // Don't worry about i here 
                return new DataHelper("Word " + i, "Meaning " + i, "Sentence " + i);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Now, every time we call the server we get an updated DataHelper which we want to show on the label(s).

To approach this, we declare a variable `dataHelper` and bind its properties to the `textProperty()` of various labels :

```
DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper("Word", "Meaning", "Sentence");
wordLabel.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.wordProperty());
meaningLabel.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.meaningProperty());
sentenceLabel.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.sentenceProperty());
```

*Now you must be wondering, how will we update `dataHelper`, right?* Well, that's the easy part. This can be can taken care in `setOnSucceeded()` of Service, where `getValue()` will return us a new instance of `DataHelper` with ***updated*** values.

```
service.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    dataHelper.setWord(service.getValue().getWord());
    dataHelper.setMeaning(service.getValue().getMeaning());
    dataHelper.setSentence(service.getValue().getSentence());
});
```

---

### Complete MCVE :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // Properties
        DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper("Word", "Meaning", "Sentence");
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

        // UI elements
        Label wordLabel = new Label();
        Label meaningLabel = new Label();
        Label sentenceLabel = new Label();
        Button startService = new Button("Start");

        Service<DataHelper> service = new Service<DataHelper>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<DataHelper> createTask() {
                return new Task<DataHelper>() {
                    @Override
                    protected DataHelper call() throws Exception {
                        i.incrementAndGet();
                        return new DataHelper("Word " + i, "Meaning " + i, "Sentence " + i);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        startService.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(service.getState().equals(Worker.State.READY) || service.getState().equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
                service.restart();
            }
        });

        service.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            dataHelper.setWord(service.getValue().getWord());
            dataHelper.setMeaning(service.getValue().getMeaning());
            dataHelper.setSentence(service.getValue().getSentence());
        });

        wordLabel.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.wordProperty());
        meaningLabel.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.meaningProperty());
        sentenceLabel.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.sentenceProperty());

        VBox box = new VBox(10, wordLabel, meaningLabel, sentenceLabel, startService);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class DataHelper {
        StringProperty word = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty meaning = new SimpleStringProperty();
        StringProperty sentence = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public DataHelper(String word, String meaning, String sentence) {
            this.word.setValue(word);
            this.meaning.setValue(meaning);
            this.sentence.setValue(sentence);
        }

        public String getMeaning() {
            return meaning.get();
        }

        public StringProperty meaningProperty() {
            return meaning;
        }

        public void setMeaning(String meaning) {
            this.meaning.set(meaning);
        }

        public String getSentence() {
            return sentence.get();
        }

        public StringProperty sentenceProperty() {
            return sentence;
        }

        public void setSentence(String sentence) {
            this.sentence.set(sentence);
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word.get();
        }

        public StringProperty wordProperty() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word.set(word);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```